# <a id> overrides <div id>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following `div` whose `id` is connected with CSS code that allows the `span` text to appear on a small tooltip window when passing the mouse over the `a` tag text.

```
<div id="tooltip">
        <p class="bid1_pm" id="valorm">Valor de mercado</p>
        <a href="#" class="bid1_pr">Reserva<span>Este é o valor mínimo de licitação para a compra do produto.</span></a>
 </div>
```

The `p` tag `id` allows me to change the `p` tag content with this javascript code

```
document.getElementById("valorm").innerHTML = "Valor de mercado " + valorm;
```

This works fine but when i try to give an id to the `a` tag

```
<a href="#" class="bid1_pr" id="reser">
```

i'm able to change the content of this tag with javascript code

```
var vres = reserva * parseInt(valorm);
 document.getElementById("reser").innerHTML = "Reserva (" + (reserva*100).toLocaleString() + "%) " + vres.toFixed(2).toLocaleString() + "€ (?)";
```

but i loose the tooltip window!!!

It seems that this third id on the `a` tag overrides the first id on the `div` tag

Can anyone help me?

Comment: On the title it's not <p> id but <a> id

Comment: But you are keeping the `span` element when replace the content of a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the ID that's stopping the tooltip from appearing, it's the fact that when you're setting the `innerHTML` on the `a` tag, you're removing the `span` entirely.  You need to update your code so it keeps the span in place:

```
var vres = reserva * parseInt(valorm);
document.getElementById("reser").innerHTML = "Reserva (" + (reserva*100).toLocaleString() + "%) " + vres.toFixed(2).toLocaleString() + "€ (?)<span>Este é o valor mínimo de licitação para a compra do produto.</span>";
```

or alternatively restructure your HTML / CSS so the `span` doesn't sit within the `a` tag.